# Which configuration file should I edit to configure file type association?

Tags: configuration, file-association

I am using ubuntu 18.04. I am trying to change PHP file association with sublime text and it is currently associated with foxit reader. I tried to change it by using "open with" menu option.But it doesn't apply even after I restarted my computer. So I need to change it by my own without using menu options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Edit the file `~/.local/config/mimeapps.list` and under the `[Default Applications]` add `application/x-php=sublime.desktop;`, if that's the name of sublime desktop file.

```
[Default Applications]
...
application/x-php=sublime.desktop;
```