# Can't open arduino files via arduino ide DIRECTLY

Tags: 18.04, files, arduino

I have arduino ide and a lot of arduino files(.ino) ,but I can't open them directly via arduino ide instead of visual studio code or others text editors I have.
I go to (properties -> Open With) or (Open with other application) and I don't find arduino ide anywhere.
What's wrong?

Ubuntu 18.04.5
Arduino Ide 1.8.13

Thanks!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install latest Arduino IDE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025753/how-to-install-latest-arduino-ide) - use version from `umake` instead of Snap or local install.

Comment: I can open arduino ide but I can not open ino files directly with arduino ide.I have to open ide and then use Ctrl+O to open a file.I want to do it directly

Comment: Sounds like you want to set up a file association for that file type. There should be plenty of topics about that here, for example [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219881/which-configuration-file-should-i-edit-to-configure-file-type-association) one.